# In kotlin keep a map of string to class type and later check if object's class type is part of the map values

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, class, types

I'm solving a problem to check the object is part of limited class types. For example I have classes of

```
class MyClass(int id) {}
class YourClass(int id) {}
```

And there's another function that runs and returns just object

```
Object run() {}
val test = run()
if (test instanceof MyClass) {}
if (test instanceof YourClass) {}
```

Instead of doing this manual comparison, is it possible to keep a map of class name to class type such as

```
val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
```

and reference the map to check if the return object is part of the map's values?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear exactly what you're doing. Can you expand your pseudo-code in the second code block above into an actual function so we can see exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you need strings there? `setOf(MyClass::class, YourClass::class)` and then you check `if (run()::class in setOfClasses)`. But it sounds a little like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What do you really try to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your immediate question, you can write a function like the following `isProperType`

This utilizes the `::class` property to determine the structure of the object, and if it is registered inside the list, we then can automatically determine this type is in the proper type we need.

There are many ways to accomplish that use stronger type referencing such as generics. This approach does neglect the strength of a typed system somewhat.

```
class FirstClass(val id: Int)
class SecondClass(val id: Int)

val registeredTypes = listOf(
    FirstClass::class, SecondClass::class
)

fun List<*>.isProperType(value: Any): Boolean {
    return contains(value::class)
}

fun getObject(): Any {
    return FirstClass(2)
}

val myObject = getObject()
val nonRegistered = "Not an expected object"

val isProper = registeredTypes.isProperType(myObject)
val isNotProper = registeredTypes.isProperType(nonRegistered)

println("Expect true for myObject: $isProper") // Expect true for myObject: true
println("Expect false for nonRegistered: $isNotProper") // Expect false for nonRegistered: false
```

Comment: wow thanks! in the object example, is it possible to reference the variable of myObject..? seems that can only be achieved by manual cast check if (myObject is FirstClass).. ?

Comment: This would require usage of the type system to our advantage, if you can give me examples of what you're trying to do, I can give you a stronger answer with generics that would be a better code pattern

Comment: The problem I have is trying to use jexl to evaluate bunch of rules, each of the evaluation is an object and can be stored in jexl's context map so if there's any other rules based on previous result, they can reference it and its properties. As I know each expression's expected output type, I want to build a map with map<String, ClassType> and during the evaluation check and cast the object and store it...

Comment: This is kind of impossible in Kotlin, you can cheat the system some, but it will never properly know the type without using the typecating. I think the effort of maintaining a map is the same as writing out these checks as the "registered" set. I'll update with an example, but I think this is the best that can be done to support this in Kotlin, short of diving into some dark magic Reflection that I don't know. Even generics would not be able to help here since it wouldn't know what type you're looking for.